# Preserve //go:generate comment in protobuf files

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

I want to do some code generations on code generated by protoc through `go:generate`. However, when it was compiled by protoc, comments are reformed into `// go:generate`, where a space was inserted, which fails go generate.

Is there a way to preserve comments(do it properly) as it is in protoc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally end up with using bash to replace them.

```
for filename in ./pkg/rpc/*.go; do
    sed -i "s#// go:generate#//go:generate#g" $filename
done
```